# why is my switch in react native is disappeared

Tags: react-native, switch-statement

my code is :  `<Switch value={isGlutenFree} onValueChange={(isPressGlutenFree) => setIsGlutenFree(isPressGlutenFree) } trackColor={{ true: Colors.mainColor }} collapsable={false} onTintColor="#ccc" />`
It is working at first [before toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Ken.png)
and after I toggle the switch he became like this [after toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0lee.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch is still rendered in your second screenshot; it's just difficult to see because the contrast with the background color is low